# many-to-many relationship for JPA on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

Can anyone provide a code sample regarding to how to implement many-to-many relationship with JPA on Google App Engine? I tried JDO and it seems to work by maintaining a Collection of each other. However, I could not make JPA work.

Answer (score 1):

Using which version of the GAE JDO/JPA plugin? As their docs say very clearly, Many-Many is not supported with v1 of that plugin. It is also not supported for "owned relations" with v2 of the plugin (though is for "unowned relations" with v2 of the plugin).